# How to send device token to XMPP for multiple device registration in same id and receive notification when application killed or in background?

Tags: android, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging, ejabberd, smack

How to configure XMPP for offline mode and receive notification from FCM?

How can I send below The IQ Push stanza to XMPP using Smack?

```
<iq type='set' id='123'>
 <push xmlns='p1:push'>
 <keepalive max="120"/>
 <session duration="60"/>
 <body send="all" groupchat="true" from="jid"/>
 <status type="xa">Text Message when in push mode</status>
 <offline>false</offline>
 <notification>
 <type>gcm</type>
 <id>registrationId</id>
 </notification>
 <appid>applicationId</appid>
 </push>
</iq>
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you are trying to do? Not sure what you mean by "send device token to XMPP"

Comment: i want to send custom IQ Stenza for push notification with firebase refreshtoken to XMPP server when initialize connection @ArthurThompson